# intel_pstate static frequency

Tags: 14.04

I am doing some research on frequency scaling and I need to run different experiments on different static frequencies. I can  easily   map a static frequency by using acpi-cpufreq drivers, but I could not manage to set a static frequency to the new intel_pstate drivers. I tried changing     cpuinfo_min_freq and cpuinfo_max_freq in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq and also try to change it from pstate-frequency -G -n and pstate-frequency -G -m, but couldn’t manage to make it work.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling -> gives a hint that you may want to play with intel_pstate via /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate , here is reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is

`sudo cpupower frequency-set -f <frequency>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but after running the command I got the following error.

root@Hp:/home/moazzam# cpupower frequency-set -f 800000 Setting cpu: 0 Error setting new values. Common errors: - Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?) - Is the governor you requested available and modprobed? - Trying to set an invalid policy? - Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available, for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?

Comment: @malik -  Are you running as root, or using sudo to execute the command?  Is the 800 Khz frequency a valid one for your CPU?

Comment: I am running it as a root and yeah 800 khz is a valid frequency. I tried  the same frequency with  cpufreq drivers and it worked.

Comment: Ah - are you actually runnning the intel_pstate then?

Comment: Yes and I need tp run all the test on intel_pstate drivers.  I did a lot research,how to set a static frequency in intel_pstate but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply, but after running the command I got the following error.

```
# cpupower frequency-set -f 800000
Setting cpu: 0
Error setting new values. Common errors:
- Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
- Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
- Trying to set an invalid policy?
- Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
   for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency
   or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a kernel parameter `intel_pstate=passive` to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=passive"
```

Then update grub with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

After rebooting, you can e.g. disable turbo frequencies with:

```
$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/
$ cp policy0/base_frequency policy0/scaling_max_freq
$ cp policy1/base_frequency policy1/scaling_max_freq
```

Important: if you have hyperthreading, you have virtual cores. And both virtual cores need a limit, before the physical core respects that limit.

So in my example above, policy0 and policy1 are for two virtual cores that map to the first physical core.